# How to list all nodes attached to a vocabulary?

Tags: nodes, 8

I have a custom vocabulary called "healthcare_terms" that has enabled terms attached to a custom content type called "health_posts".

I just want to find all nodes that are tagged with enabled terms from "healthcare_terms"

I tried the following but it does not seem to be working.

```
   $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('type', 'health_posts')
      ->condition('status', 1)
      ->condition('field_tags.entity.name', 'healthcare_terms');
    $ids = $query->execute();
```

Clearly I am lost. Any help or tips?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you are using the tags field for this?

You're filtering on the term name, but you want to filter on the term vid instead:

```
 $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'health_posts')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->condition('field_tags.entity.vid', 'healthcare_terms');
$ids = $query->execute();
```

If you have a standalone field that only allows terms from your healthcare_terms vocabulary, which is usually the better approach, then you can just look for ->exists('field_something').